# Ugly spacing when using \binom

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

The rendering of binomial expressions in MathJax seems a bit off. The spacings are a bit too large in my opinion and it looks a tiny bit asymmetrical.

**Inline**

Lorem $10+\binom32\times\binom xy$ ipsum.

**Displaystyle**

$$10+\binom32\times\binom xy$$

---

Screenshot from my computer (running Chrome on Windows 7):

[image]

---

To be clear, I mean the spacings around the parentheses.

[image]

Comment: It does look asymmetric, the multiplication symbol is closer to the left binom than the right.

Comment: The asymmetry is a bit strange. What I also find strange is to use `\times` to indicate multiplication :-) To each their own I guess. Compare
$$10+\binom32\times\binom xy$$
and
$$10+\binom32\binom xy$$
and
$$10+\binom32\cdot\binom xy$$
and
$$(1,-2,3)\times(2,1,4).$$
In a cross product $\times$ seems to be symmetrically placed. Also in a product of two binomials the centered dot is also asymmetrically placed. May be the problem is with the sizing of that imaginary box surrounding that large parens in the binomial?

Comment: The large left parens in particular seems to cause a lof of white space to its left. The plus sign between $10$ and the binomial coefficient is IMVHO not centered either. May be Davide Cervone will see this and can explain things?

Comment: I find one way to reduce the asymmetric white space is surround the middle operator by `{}`.
$$
\begin{array}{c:c}
\binom{3}{2}\cdot\binom{x}{y} & \binom{3}{2}\times\binom{x}{y}\\
\binom{3}{2}{\cdot}\binom{x}{y} & \binom{3}{2}{\times}\binom{x}{y}\\
\end{array}$$
`\begin{array}{c:c}
\binom{3}{2}\cdot\binom{x}{y} & \binom{3}{2}\times\binom{x}{y}\\
\binom{3}{2}{\cdot}\binom{x}{y} & \binom{3}{2}{\times}\binom{x}{y}\\
\end{array}`

Comment: It looks like a bug in the HTML-CSS and SVG output jax.  The space between the cross and the parenthesis is being inserted twice. I haven't looked into why, but I started an [issue tracker](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/889) for it on the MathJax github site.  Thanks for reporting the issue.  It appears to only affect situations with `\left` and `\right` (or constructs that use stretchy delimiters like this).

Comment: @DavideCervone Great, thanks!

Comment: The issue is easily fixed and will be corrected in the next release of MathJax.  See the issue tracker linked above.

Comment: @DavideCervone It probably does not make much difference (the only I can think of is that this question will not be shown as unanswered), but perhaps you could post your comments as an answer. (The question has been recently bumped anyway.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was fixed in version 2.5 of MathJax.  See the [issue tracker](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/889) on the MathJax GitHub site.  As you can see, the live examples in the original post are now displayed properly.